# snmpwalk -- Gives no output and no error either

Tags: linux, snmp, snmpwalk

I'm running the command snmpwalk -v 1 localhost -c public .1.3.6.1.4.1.10876

The command does not give any errors such as timeout and it also does not output anything. echo $? after running the command outputs 0. Any suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 0):

what do you expect to be returned?
Can you check if you get any output from the snmpwalk by running snmpd in debug mode?

```
snmpd -D -Le -f
```

Comment: Yes the command you suggested gave a very long output. I am trying to use snmp with super doctor. On my other server the command i mentioned outputs a large amount of lines